# Лицензия на github для аккаунта-портфолио

Tags: github, лицензирование

Собираюсь создавать аккаунт на github, выложить туда несколько небольших проектов для портфолио. Подскажите пожалуйста, какую лицензию лучше выбрать для таких небольших проектов? И нужна ли вообще лицензия на такую мелочь (если у меня только для портфолио), носит ли она обязательный характер?

Comment: Пока лицензия не указана - все права у вас как у автора по умолчаию. Указание лицензии - не обязательно.